# Julia: Sort Matrix by column 2 then 3

Tags: sorting, matrix, julia

I would like to sort my matrix `A` by column 2 then 3.

```
A = round.(randn(100,4))
```

Maybe something like:

```
sort(A,(0,2:3))
100x4 Array{Float64,2}:
  0.0  -2.0  -2.0  -1.0
 -1.0  -2.0  -1.0   1.0
  1.0  -2.0  -1.0   2.0
 -1.0  -2.0   0.0   0.0
 -1.0  -2.0   0.0  -1.0
 -0.0  -2.0   0.0  -1.0
  1.0  -2.0   0.0   0.0
  1.0  -2.0   1.0  -1.0
 -0.0  -2.0   2.0  -1.0
 -0.0  -1.0  -2.0   1.0
  ⋮                    
 -0.0   1.0   0.0   1.0
  1.0   1.0   1.0   1.0
  0.0   1.0   1.0  -1.0
 -0.0   1.0   2.0   0.0
 -0.0   2.0  -1.0   0.0
 -2.0   2.0  -1.0   1.0
  2.0   2.0  -0.0  -1.0
 -1.0   2.0  -0.0  -1.0
  1.0   2.0   0.0   2.0
 -1.0   2.0   2.0   0.0
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

There is a `sortslices` function that takes a `by` keyword that lets you do this:

```
julia> sortslices(A, dims=1, by=x->(x[2], x[3]))
100x4 Array{Float64,2}:
  2.0  -3.0  -0.0   0.0
 -1.0  -2.0  -1.0  -1.0
 -0.0  -2.0  -0.0   0.0
  0.0  -2.0   0.0  -1.0
  1.0  -2.0   1.0   2.0
 -0.0  -2.0   1.0  -1.0
 -1.0  -1.0  -2.0   1.0
 -1.0  -1.0  -2.0  -0.0
 -1.0  -1.0  -1.0   1.0
 -0.0  -1.0  -1.0   0.0
  ⋮
 -0.0   1.0   1.0  -1.0
 -0.0   1.0   2.0   1.0
  0.0   1.0   2.0   0.0
 -1.0   2.0  -2.0   1.0
  0.0   2.0  -2.0  -2.0
  1.0   2.0  -1.0   0.0
  0.0   2.0  -1.0  -0.0
 -1.0   2.0   0.0  -1.0
 -0.0   2.0   2.0   0.0
  1.0   3.0   2.0   1.0
```

The sorting API is pretty flexible – you can find documentation [here](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/sort/).

Comment: And, more in general, `sortslices(A,dims=1,by=x->(x[2],x[3]),rev=false)`

Comment: `sortrows` was deprecated in Julia 0.7. Recommendation is to use `sortslices(A, dims=1, kws...)` instead.