# Matrices in Julia - Sorting and Sort Permutations

Tags: sorting, matrix, julia

How can matrices be sorted in `Julia`.

Let's define a matrix:

```
a = [1 1 1;
     1 3 1;
     1 2 2;
     1 2 1]
```

I'm looking for several things here:

#### Sort by multiple Columns

So, you can sort the matrix by all columns from left to right with

```
sortslices(a, dims = 1)

4×3 Array{Int64,2}:
 1  1  1
 1  2  1
 1  2  2
 1  3  1
```

#### Sort by particular Column Order

But what if want to sort by the `3rd` then the `2nd` and then the `1st` column? Expected output:

```
4×3 Array{Int64,2}:
 1  1  1
 1  2  1
 1  3  1
 1  2  2
```

#### Sort permutation

Let's assume I had a `Vector`

```
b = ["a", "d", "c", "b"]
```

and I would like to sort its elements by the sort permutation of the matrix' columns. As seen above `sortslices()` let's me sort the matrix so I get the rows in the order `[1,4,3,2]`. How can I get this vector to sort `b` to

```
4-element Array{String,1}:
 "a"
 "b"
 "c"
 "d"
```

---

I know there are other similar questions, but they seem either address other issues or they seem to be outdated (e.g. [Julia: Sort Matrix by column 2 then 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23187752/julia-sort-matrix-by-column-2-then-3)).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It isn't ideal to ask multiple questions within a single post.  It makes searching for questions much harder.

Anyway, here we go:

### Sort by multiple Columns

```
julia> a = [1 1 1;
            1 3 1;
            1 2 2;
            1 2 1]
4×3 Matrix{Int64}:
 1  1  1
 1  3  1
 1  2  2
 1  2  1

julia> sortslices(a, dims = 1, by=x->(x[1], x[2], x[3]))
4×3 Matrix{Int64}:
 1  1  1
 1  2  1
 1  2  2
 1  3  1
```

### Sort by particular Column Order

```
julia> a = [1 1 1;
            1 3 1;
            1 2 2;
            1 2 1]
4×3 Matrix{Int64}:
 1  1  1
 1  3  1
 1  2  2
 1  2  1

julia> sortslices(a, dims = 1, by=x->(x[3], x[2], x[1]))
4×3 Matrix{Int64}:
 1  1  1
 1  2  1
 1  3  1
 1  2  2
```

### Sort permutation

```
julia> b = ["a", "d", "c", "b"]
4-element Vector{String}:
 "a"
 "d"
 "c"
 "b"

julia> sortperm(b)
4-element Vector{Int64}:
 1
 4
 3
 2

julia> b[sortperm(b)]
4-element Vector{String}:
 "a"
 "b"
 "c"
 "d"
```

Comment: Thanks. That's very helpful. The last part is not what I was looking for, though. What I want is to sort the *vector* by the *sort permutation of the matrix*.

Comment: You do `b[sortperm(b)]`, but I am looking for the function `foo` that does `b[foo(a)]`.

Comment: Not sure I follow.  `a` is a 4x3 `Matrix`, `b` is a 4-element `Vector`.  How that would work?

Comment: Maybe you want `p = sortperm(collect(eachrow(a)), by = x->(x[3], x[2], x[1]))`

Comment: Yes, that is what I want. It's hard to completely understand, what the code does, though. Wanna make it an answer?

Comment: @giordano Yes, `a` is a matrix, but it is sorted hierarchically by the 3 columns. Hence, the **4 rows** are permutated and I would like to get the permutation. This permutation is a 4-element vector that puts `a` in order (`a[my_perm]`). @mcabbotts solution does the trick.

Answer (score 1):

Building on @mcabbot's comment, I think that `by` clause is unnecessary. This suffices: `p = sortperm(collect(eachrow(a)))`.

Whether this is the most performant solution, I don't know.